# How to migrate routes using rabbitmq compoment in Camel 4.x

Tags: apache-camel

We have implemented a simple routing engine application based on Apache Camel 3.x, with support for dynamic routes configuration loading: other applications can extend the routing engine by adding route definition files in XML DSL in a dedicated directory, let's say `/etc/routing-engine/routes.d/`.

The engine supports only few components , like `rabbit-mq` and `http`, plus some custom components.
Routes added by application can look like:

```
<route id="my-custom-route">
    <from uri="rabbitmq:myexchange?queue=myqueueName&amp;autoDelete=false&amp;exchangeType=topic"/>
    <log message="MyApp event received , routing to http server" />
    <setHeader name="Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE">
        <constant>application/json</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <setHeader name="productId">
        <jsonpath suppressExceptions="true">$.productId</jsonpath>
    </setHeader>
    <toD uri="commonhttpcomponent:/v1/generic/.."/>
</route>
```

Now, we would like to prepare upgrade of the engine to Camel 4.x ( release 4.0.0-RC1 is now available), and I wonder how to deal with existing routes , since the [camel-rabbit](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/rabbitmq-component.html) component is no longer supported, in favor of [spring-rabbitmq-component](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.20.x/spring-rabbitmq-component.html) component, as mentioned in the Camel 4.x migration guide [removed components](https://camel.apache.org/manual/camel-4-migration-guide.html#_removed_components)

We cannot easily upgrade all existing routes at the same time: they are not delivered by the same teams and not packaged together.

I was thinking of creating a temporary "fake" component attached to the "rabbitmq:" uri, that would act as a kind of "alias" to the know "spring-rabbitmq:" component, to handle the migration smoothly . New routes delivered by other applications will directly use the "spring-rabbitmq" component.

I have tried to register a component like :

```
/**
 * Simple "alias" component to replace route endpoints with "rabbitmq:*" uris with the new recommended spring-rabbitmq component.
 */
public class RabbitMQComponent extends SpringRabbitMQComponent {

    private static final List<String> REMOVED_PARAMETERS = List.of("autoDelete");

    @Override
    protected Endpoint createEndpoint(String uri, String remaining, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws Exception {
        String newUri = uri.replace("rabbitmq:", "spring-rabbitmq:");
        Map<String, Object> updatedParameters = new HashMap<>();
        parameters.forEach((key, value) -> {
            if ("queue".equals(key)) {
                updatedParameters.put("queues", value);
            } else if (!REMOVED_PARAMETERS.contains(key)) {
                updatedParameters.put(key, value);
            }
        });
        return super.createEndpoint(newUri, remaining, updatedParameters);
    }
}
```

This will not work, as some parameters from the `rabbitmq` component do not exit on `spring-rabbitmq`, so the paramters validation will fail here https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/core/camel-support/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/support/DefaultComponent.java#L191 even with the "trick" I tried to implement (e.g. renaming parameter  `queue` to `queues` )

Do you see some alternative solutions to implement such compatibility/migration task?